# Optimizing : constructing a jquery collection

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have this Jquery code that construct a collection of jquery objects. It takes around 600 ms to execute.
I want to optimize it:

```
var tousBt = $('img.boutonReduire');
var stack = $('');
tousBt.each( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    stack = stack.add('#table' + id).add('#img' + id);
  });
```

Do you see something that I can do ? The result has to be a collection of jquery objects.

Edit: I get all the stacks elements and hide them : stack.addClass('hideit'); There is around 125 elements. And $('*').length give around 7100 elements.

Comment: corrected the code to show tousBt

Comment: And what is the value of the `id` attributes? Or: what are you actually going to do with `stack` afterwards? Just in case there are some jQuery magics that can solve your problem better ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, remove the assignment operation inside your iteration function. `stack` is an instance---there's no need to reassign it:

```
var tousBt = $('img.boutonReduire');
var stack = $('');
tousBt.each( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    stack.add('#table' + id).add('#img' + id);
});
```

I'd also suggest getting away from jQuery overhead if you're calling `add()` a tons of times. Here's a version using a lightweight array to accumulate the selectors:

```
var tousBt = $('img.boutonReduire');
var stack = [];
tousBt.each( function() {
    var id = this.id;
    stack.push('#table' + id);
    stack.push('#img' + id);
});
```

Then, to get the finalized selector that you can use with jQuery:

```
var selector = stack.join(','); 
//$(stack.join(','));
```

**Edit:** this may seem absolutely retarded, but this *might* actually be fastest (worth a shot at least):

```
var tousBt = $('img.boutonReduire');
tousBt.each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $('#table' + id).addClass('selected');
    $('#img' + id).addClass('selected');
});
var stack = $('.selected');
```

Comment: Think this "var id = $(this).attr('id');" can be replaced with just "var id = this.id".

Comment: Really a good idea. This minimize Jquery utilization. But in my case it does not help. I get a 2000 ms to construct the Jquery object only. FYI: There is 125 elements in the result stack list. I'm surprised by the result though.

Comment: Another point is to move out of the loop the "addClass('selected')" and run it ones on stack object: stack.addClass('selected');

Comment: Well, that'd defeat the purpose of applying the class for mass selection purposes.

Comment: Good idea too. Thanks ! The performance is better with 1500 ms. The problem is that selecting by classname do not have a native implementation in the browser (IE) so this is penalizing.
Kamarey, thanks for the input, the var id = this.id works and helps a little !

Comment: Modified a little bit your solution : var stack = $('table.selected, img.selected');
This help a little. The performance drop to 1200 ms. But what is strange is that subsequent call to it now gives 300 ms. Seems that the browser or Jquery is caching the selection.